# Export all default imports from typescript file

Tags: typescript, svg, import, export, dry

I have an index.tsx file which is a convenient place to import a bunch of images:

```
import BlueSquarePath from "./logo-square-block.svg";
import LoadingSpinner from "./loading-spinner.svg";
import Logo from "./logo-all-black-text.svg";
import LogoTextPath from "./logo-text-only.svg";
import UserImpactIcon from "./user-impact-icon.svg";
```

I want to then export all of these.  I can do this:

```
export { 
  BlueSquarePath, 
  LoadingSpinner, 
  Logo,
  LogoTextPath,
  UserImpactIcon
};
```

These are meant to be consumed as image paths in an image component:

```
import { UserImpactIcon } from 'assets/images';

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <img src={UserImpactIcon} />
)
```

This is in contrast to doing a `import { ReactComponent as UserImpactIcon } from './user-impact-icon.svg';`, and then using as as a standalone component (`<UserImpactIcon />`), which I beleive renders actual `svg` elements on the page, as opposed to an `img` component with a .svg file as the source.  Please correct me if I'm wrong on that.

But then as I add imports to this list, I have to double those back into the `export` statement, which seems redundant.

Is there a way to export all these default imports in a concise way that doesn't involve repeating the names twice?  Something like `export *` or `export {}`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
export * as BlueSquarePath from "./logo-square-block.svg";
export * as LoadingSpinner from "./loading-spinner.svg";
export * as Logo from "./logo-all-black-text.svg";
export * as LogoTextPath from "./logo-text-only.svg";
export * as UserImpactIcon from "./user-impact-icon.svg";
```

This imports all exports (`*`) each the file as a particular name (`as Logo`). And since there is only a default export, the `*` is that default export.

This will also work:

```
export { default as BlueSquarePath } from "./logo-square-block.svg";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected.  While weback and typescript can resolve the module, in the browser, the image cannot be found, as the `src` property of the image tag comes out as `[object Module]` - do I have to adjust something in my webpack / ts configs for this to work as expected?